# How Java handles dynamic Boolean array as method parameter?

Tags: java, arrays, methods, parameters, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm using a class that has a method that accepts a `boolean[]`.

This code does not raise any errors

```
public class myclass{
    void move(boolean[] myarray) {
         //Do stufff
    }
}
```

Now, I do a little C++ coding, and this would not work in the context of dynamic memory.

So this is essentially a java question:

In my case the array being received has a known length, but I want to know how you would handle this in Java if it is dynamic (as well as what I should do if its not dynamic).

I'm guessing the compiler or JVM is going to handle this, but I want to know the speed optimizations I can implement.

Comment: Java arrays have a `length` property you can read at runtime. Sidenote: One of the points of having your code run on a VM is NOT to do speed optimizations. The VM does most of the stuff you would do in C++ for you, usually better than you could do it yourself ;)

Comment: what do you actually mean with `handle it`?. By using `myarray.length` you get the length of the array, so this would be handling it dynamicly for me.

Comment: Don't worry about speed optimizations before you run into an actual performance problem.

Comment: @RealSkeptic - Well these bool arrays are going to be flying through this class. They represent AI control states, so I basically want to run as many as I can until it starts slowing down.

Comment: @bigcodeszzer Do that then. As with every performance-related optimisation, the process is simple: first set out a target, then measure, then optimize and repeat the last two steps until you hit the target.

Comment: @JanDoerrenhaus - Well if the bool array isn't initialized, suppose I'm passing in arrays of different lengths? I realize java can do impressive things but still, I want this thing as fast as it can go.

Comment: But if you want an arbitrary-length bit set, you should consider using the `BitSet` class, as it's cleaner that way.

Comment: Do you have any reason to think passing a boolean array is not fast enough? If not, I can't see what the issue is. Be thankful that you are not programming in C++. The fact that an array decays to a pointer is just horrible.

Comment: [This](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) might be useful reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays in Java are always constant length. From [The Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html), "The length of an array is established when the array is created."

If you wanted dynamic arrays, you'd use something from the Collections Framework, e.g. ArrayList.

In any case, a reference to the array (or collection) is passed into move(...), so there shouldn't be any difference in speed just for the function call.

When using the array, I'd expect (static) arrays to be dereferenced more quickly than going through the function calls to access elements of (dynamic) collections. However, to have a proper comparison, you'd need to provide more context of how your array is used.

Comment: So I guess you're saying that the compiler implicitly passes the length and then initializes? It's the initializing that is confusing me.

Comment: @bigcodeszzer The initialisation happens before the function call, and your move(...) method takes an (already) initialised array.

Comment: @bigcodeszzer What do you mean "and then initializes"? The array is already initialized.

Comment: @bigcodeszzer Neither. A java array is like a fully-fledged object, it has fields and a class. When you create an array with `new`, all the elements will be initialised to their default value (depending on the element type). And if you don't set a value for an array reference, it'll simply be `null`. But none of it is done by the compiler.

Comment: @bigcodeszzer Are you wondering about the empty square brackets in `boolean[]`? Java arrays carry their own length as part of the object, so the square brackets in formal parameters simply signify an array type as opposed to the non-array simple type. It doesn't signify a dynamic array.

Comment: Please correct the _by reference_ to _by value where the value is a reference to a `boolean[]` object_.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Good catch. I've edited it differently to your request as the distinction between passing a reference and passing a copy of all elements of the array is more important here than that between passing by value and passing by reference.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using ArrayList<>() for all your needs related to iterating arbitrary length collections.

Also using List is a good practice in the Java world. There is a article about programmers who use Lists and arrays and those who use lists tend to produce less bugs.

Comment: I would probably use a `BitSet` in this case rather than a list of booleans.